# Unicode class names in C# - why do some work, when others don't?

Tags: c#, unicode, special-characters

I'm wondering why this is. I have two unicode characters from the same group Ll, which is allowed according to the specs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx

One of them works, the other gives a compile error, and I can't find any documentation on why this is:

This works:

U+0467  CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER LITTLE YUS    ѧ

This don't:

U+04FF  CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA WITH STROKE    ӿ

Can you help me find the pattern?

Comment: Which version of the compiler are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

U+0467 is from Unicode 1.1, whereas U+04FF is from Unicode 5.0. The page you refer to mentions Unicode 3.0. So the compiler's Unicode databases are just not new enough.

Comment: Wow. That was a good and quick answer, thanks :) 
Can I ask where you find the version for a single character?

Comment: In this case I looked it up in the GNOME character map. Another very good source is fileformat.info: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/04ff/index.htm

Comment: Thank you for the link. It's very useful!