# equivalent WindowsFormsHost in C# winform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

what is equivalent WindowsFormsHost in C# winform?
i wrote program in C# winform. in my user control(instead of form), i put reporting. when user clicked btnReporting, rptfile is shown.
this is my code in wpf. i don't equivalent WindowsFormsHost in C# winform?

```
 CrystalReportViewer rptViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
            rptViewer.DisplayStatusBar = false;

            WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
            rptViewer.ReportSource = rep;
            host.Child = rptViewer;
            ReportRpt PageRpt = new ReportRpt();

            PageRpt.GrdReport.Children.Add(host);
            NavigationService navService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
            navService.Navigate(PageRpt);
```

Comment: Equivalent for what? `WindowsFormsHost` hosts WinForms controls in WPF. Since you're in WinForms ... you don't need a host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For showing crystal report on Winform, you may add the Crystal Viewer from the toolbox on the form and set the crystal report against it.

Please see: [Displaying Crystal Reports using WinForms and C#](http://aspalliance.com/1297_Displaying_Crystal_Reports_using_WinForms_and_C.all)

but if you want to host a WPF control in Winform then you can use [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx)

> A Windows Forms control that can be used to host a Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF) element.

Comment: +1 for answer the question and the real question ("How do I use Crystal Reports in WinForms").

Comment: i put crystal report viewer in my user control. in properties of rystal report viewer, when i select report source, didn't allow for adding report source and give me error:" UNABLE FIND RESOURCE IN MANIFEST RESOURCES"

Comment: @userUser, its a known problem with Crystal report viewer and there could be multiple reasons. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408554/unable-to-find-the-report-in-the-manifest-resources-crystal-report-c-sharp

Comment: i read this link, i set this but it didn't fix and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a windows forms host in winforms - thats just for backwards compatibility in WPF
just add the reference to crytal reports and place the control on your form

Comment: i put crystal report viewer in my user control. in properties of rystal report viewer, when i select report source, didn't allow for adding report source and give me error:" UNABLE FIND RESOURCE IN MANIFEST RESOURCES"