# Illegal characters in class names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, code-generation, edmgen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What characters are allowed in C# class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name)

I'm using [`edmgen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx) to dynamically create classes from my database. But it seems like some of the characters in table names are considered illegal and are converted to `_` (e.g. table named: `test!@#$%^&*()[]` will be converted to `test____________`.

What are the illegal characters that are being converted to `_` when generating object layer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All alphanumeric unicode characters and underscore are valid, but it cannot begin with a number, so anything not belonging in there is invalid.

- [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name)
- [More info on C# language spec here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx)