# There is braces in a C# Class name

Tags: c#

I have a class from somewhere. The name is strange, it is called "Something[into]ABC.cs".
Is it valid for "[into]" in a class name?

Comment: Is it a class or file name? Show us the contents of this file.

Comment: In what context are you seeing the name?

Comment: A class name certainly can't contain a `.`, as in `.cs` - are you sure this isn't just a file name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What characters are allowed in C# class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name)

Comment: The class name doesn't include []. But when I look at it in solution explorer, it has it.

Comment: @Love solution explorer - *on the default tab* lists *files*, not classes

Comment: Braces are {}, Brackets are [], Parenthesis are ()

Comment: @MatthewWatson it is not quite possible to be so strict about "Brackets are []"; "brackets" is also an umbrella term for about 8 types of bracket. "Square brackets" is probably the only thing you can say safely: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be noted that the CLI allows names that are illegal in C# (a trick that the C# compiler itself exploits when it "names" anonymous types): ***however*** - a type name **cannot** contain `.` (that would signify a namaspace), and a little checking shows that `[` / `]` must be escaped when used in names; so it would be `a\[b\]` (or `a\\[b\\]` when written as a C# string). I think we can conclude, therefore, that you do *not* have a class named `Something[into]ABC.cs`. I suspect you have a *file* named that instead, with the class somewhat more sane.

File names do not define the class name, although it is considered polite to keep the two in sync.