# Entity Framework: List of invalid characters in Entity Name

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I am working on a designer which is very similar to Edmx designer in Visual Studio. I want to add the same validation that Edmx designer applies to Entity and Property Names. Can someone share what are the validation rules i.e. What characters are allowed and what are not. What might be the length of Entity/Property name and other such rules?

Comment: If you´re using C#, maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the xsds. When loading artifacts (CSDL/MSL/SSDL) there is two step validation 1 - using xsd, 2 internal validation checking additional rules that in most cases cannot be expressed in xsd. 
EF6 is open source now but xsd schemas for previous versions have not changed. You can find them [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9aec1721aa76#src/EntityFramework/Resources/System/Data/EntityModel/System.Data.Resources.CSDLSchema_3.xsd). (Schemas for mapping are in the MappingSpecification folder).

If you look at v3 CSDL schema the name of the property is specified as follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="TSimpleIdentifier">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="480" />
        <!-- The below pattern represents the allowed identifiers in ECMA specification -->
        <xs:pattern value="[\p{L}\p{Nl}][\p{L}\p{Nl}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Pc}\p{Cf}]{0,}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

If you don't want to bother with xsds and would like to take advantage of the internal validation you can just load your xml to the corresponding item collection. Again in EF6 there have been some overloads added that allows you load artifacts but will not throw an exception if they are invalid but would return null and a list of errors as an out parameter (look for public static factory methods on item collections).