# C# Escaping String Identifier When Declaring Variable

Tags: c#, escaping, identifier

Is there a way to declare a variable that has symbol involved? Such as:

```
int MIN% = 0;
```

or

```
string DE/M = "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Variable Naming Rules - C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615485%28v=vs.88%29.aspx)

> - The first character of a variable name must be either a letter, an    underscore character (_), or the at symbol (@).
> - Subsequent characters may be letters, underscore characters, or    numbers.

You can't have any special character other than `_` in variable name, *(OR @ symbol as the first character)* - So there is no point escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

C# is based on the Unicode character set.  You can include *certain* (many, in fact) symbols in identifiers.  For example, the following is valid code that will compile:

```
int myΔ = 1;
myΔ++;

int \u0066 = 1;
\u0066++;
```

As to the specific examples given (`%`, `/`), both are illegal characters in identifiers (most likely because they have other meaning within the language as operators).

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name) as well as [the C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx) provide additional information.