# How to find all static constructors?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a large Visual Studio solution of many C# projects. How to find all the static constructors? We had a few bugs where some did silly things, I want to check the others.

Comment: grep the codebase? Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: maybe a simple regex like "static \w+\(" may help finding

Comment: @HimBromBeere: using `\w` is actually simpler and covers more cases. I updated my answer in this direction. Thx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can search in code using a regular expression.

Try this one:

```
static\s+\w+\s*\(
```

[image: search box]

<s>You may adjust the character set if you allow your developers to use other [than letter, numbers and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name).</s> Simplified regex using `\w`

This works because other uses of the `static` keyword requires at least a return type.

Answer (score 4):

I think using reflection is fastest way to achieve it. You can add new project to solution and write small piece of code (perhaps save constructor names to text file):

```
public static IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> GetAllStaticConstructorsInSolution()
{
   var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

   return assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.DefinedTypes
                   .Where(type => type.DeclaredConstructors.Any(constructorInfo => constructorInfo.IsStatic))
                   .SelectMany(x => x.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Static)))
                   .Distinct();
}
```

Above Linq query should work although I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using reflection over the built assemblies rather than searching the source code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70wxday(v=vs.110).aspx This might be faster/easier than grepping the text.

You could also look at tools like NDepend: http://www.ndepend.com/  It will actually let you write linq queries over the code.  It's not cheap, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ildasm and dump the assembly, then search the .il file for **.cctor** (not .ctor, use the extra c). Static constructors are implemented with **.cctor** methods.

```
ildasm program.exe /out=program.il
```

Example:

```
.method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static
        void  .cctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Static constructor"
  IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Animal::.cctor
```