# Class naming alternatives to the underscore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, naming-conventions

Dashes `-` can't be used in C# to name classes. Are there any good character alternatives, other than underscores? `_`

I'm looking for a character to add some readability to longer class names. Thanks!

Looking to not use casing methods.. Something to replace this underscore...
I find this to look horrible at a glance..

```
ClassAIsThisFirstVariable
ClassAIsThisSecondVariable
ClassAIsThisThirdsVariable
```

Just looking for an underscore replacement..

```
ClassAIsThis_FirstVariable
ClassAIsThis_SecondVariable
ClassAIsThis_ThirdVariable
```

Comment: just use proper casing like `ThisIsAReallyLongClassName`

Comment: Could you provide concrete example? Usually Pascal casing is enough. Problems occur mainly for the words that can be either noun or a verb.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that my eyes start to blur when I use casing methods for this particular scenario. A separate would be great, but I'm almost physically allergic to underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) for some options.

Note that the underscore is the most standard character for this purpose so to my opinion, replacing it will actually lead to less readability...

Comment: I just hate them. I'm looking for anything else.