# Type is not given valid in the context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have created two forms namely Form1 and Form2 their is a Button in form two when the Button is clicked Form2 should be displayed.But I keep getting the error "Form2 Type is not valid in the context"

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 in = new Form2();
        in.show();
    }
}
```

[image: Image from application]

Comment: use another name for your instance [ in ] is not valid for name

Answer (score 1):

`in` is a keywork of C# and you can't use it as a name for a variable. Change it or use `@` in front of it:

```
MyClass @in = new MyClass();
@in.Something();
```

Read more here: [What characters are allowed in C# class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/950616/6400526)