# EF Core migration error: PositionalParameterNotFound,Add-Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with EntityFrameWork When I try to Run Command Add-Migration, I'm getting the following error

```
Add-Migration migration space
```

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Add-Migration
```

I find that this error occurred because there is a 'space' in the migration name. I also cannot create migration With special-Chars. Can some explain to me what are rules to be followed to add a new migration

Answer (score 3):

Migrations generate classes, so the migration name needs to be a valid C# class name.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name) covers the naming rules for classes.